# Error with Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt, android-appcompat

I had installed every think correctly SDK,JRE ect..... and I tryied many solution from youtube but doesn't work .
there is an error sign on appcompat_v7 and an excalamtion on my project 
I used to work with Eclipse on java project perfectly unless I installed ADT,errors came up.

(4 Errors )Description  :

1. error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
   matches the given name
   'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
   75  Android AAPT Problem
2. The container 'Android
           Dependencies' references non existing library
           'C:\Users\ayman\workspaceJavaMars\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'    HappyBirthday       Build

   path    Build Path Problem
3. The project cannot be built
   until build path errors are resolved    HappyBirthday       Unknown Java
   Problem
4. Description Resource    Path    Location    Type Unparsed aapt error(s)!
   Check the console for output.   HappyBirthday       line 1  Android ADT
   Problem

Comment: You must Google `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'`... **A LOT** results will return,

Comment: I resolved finally I just had to install latest version of android 22, but still a warning showing in my project ActionBarActivity with a line at it.